# Htaccess not redirecting to new base

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I would like to redirect anything that does not begin with `/X`, to `/X`, and, I'm trying to do this by using `.htaccess` with this content:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(?!/X)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /X/$1
```

What am I missing?

EDIT:
I've also tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/X
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /X/$1 [L]
```

and using [this tool](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be/) seems like it should work, but for example `www.site.com/style.css`

It's now working...

Answer (score 0):

Have it like this:

```sh
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+alsiniga/X[/?\s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /alsiniga/X%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: this works too in the validator, but not on the server

Comment: That online tool you're using is totally useless. Make sure to test on your own Apache only. If that's not working please tell your full URL that didn't redirect?

Comment: sure, the "X" is "alsiniga" folder, the url is `http://localhost:8080/alsiniga/file.css`... my problem is that inside all the file in my project are using absolute path, this means that `/alsiniga/index.html` refers to `/style.css` that is actually inside `http://localhost:8080/alsiniga/style.css`... I've added the `.htaccess` in both `/` and in `/alsiniga/` but it's not working... maybe the virtualhost of apache has as root `/alsiniga/` and so it ignore the `htaccess` in `/`